# How to send a String as html attachment in Android mail?

Tags: android, html, string, email-attachments

I would like to attach string as html attachment in android mail,how can I achieve this.Kindly help me with a snippet to do this.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent to send email like below way .. and if u want to add some string as attachment u have to save that content into some directory with .html ext and later u can add it as attachment into email intent.  [This code for idea it may need few modification as per ur app requirement..]

```
    String emailText = "email message";
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "demo@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hi");       
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);

    String attachContent = "<html> content </html>";
    /* this method u have to write, to save the string into html file 
    into cache or any other dir */
      saveFile(getCacheDir()+"/attach.html", attachContent );
      File file = new File(root, getCacheWebDir()+"/attach.html");
      Uri uri  = Uri.fromFile(file);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
      this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```